# Ngrx Store Redux of Angular won't work in Ionic 3 App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I want to implement [ngrx store](https://github.com/ngrx/store) for my **Ionic 3 App**. They said that **ngrx** was inspired by [redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux). So I will try **ngrx/store** for a large app for a better **state management** of the whole **app** and make it **centralize**.

But whenever I try this line of code below to import this in my **AppModules** of my app.

```
// in the imports provider array 
StoreModule.forRoot({ counter: counterReducer }),
```

or this one below:

```
// Same implementation above
  StoreModule.provideStore({ counter: counterReducer })
```

I got an error that said below that

> Uncaught TypeError:
>   **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core**.OpaqueToken is not a constructor

When I try to open the **StoreModule** import from **@ngrx/store**

I saw this import above that it can't find the **OpaqueToken**

```
import { OpaqueToken, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
```

This is my **ionic info** below

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.0-rc.13 (/home/clifford/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11

System:

NodeJS : v6.12.2 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 4.6.1
   OS     : Linux 4.13

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the **issue** by doing

```
npm install @ngrx/store@5
```

But I have another issue error below when I import the **StoreModule.forRoot**

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'schedule' of
>   undefined ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ;

You also need to install [zone.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zone.js?activeTab=readme) from the issue above.

in my **case** I used this `npm i zone.js@^0.8.4 --save`

Comment: npm install @ngrx/store@5 not doing it for me unfortunately